# Why does p{margin: 0} have no effect when the <p> is included in a <div>?

Tags: html, css

When trying to reduce the space between two p tags, I did the following in the html file:

```
<div id="p1"> paragraph1 </p> </div>
<div id="p2"> paragraph2 </p> </div>
```

and did the following in the css file:

```
#p1{
   margin:0;
  }

#p2{
   margin:0;
  }
```

it doesn't work. But if I change the content in the html file into:

```
<p id="p1">   paragraph1 </p> 
<p id="p2">   paragraph2 </p>
```

then it works. In other words, not using div works. Why can't the margin:0; work when the p tags are inside the div tags?

EDIT: I made some typos in the questions. I'm sorry for that. When I was trying to reduce the space between the p tags, I correctly used #p1 and #p2 in the css file. Secondly I didn't nest the p tags. I have corrected those typos in the questions.

EDIT2: This is the original code in the html file.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> title </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="pcss.css">
</head>


    <body>

        <div id="container">

            <div  id="p1">
            <p> Paragraph1 </p>
             </div> 



             <div  id="p2">
            <p> paragraph2</p>
             </div>


        </div>


    </body>
```

and the orignal code in the css file.

```
body{
background-color:black;}

#container{
background-color:grey;
width:600px;
height:600px;
margin:auto;}

#blank{
background-color:white;}

#p1{
color:white; 
width:600px;
text-align:center;
background-color:#666699; 
font-size:0.8cm; 
margin:0;}

#p2{
color:white; 
width:600px;
text-align:center;
background-color:#666699; 
font-size:0.8cm; 
margin:0;}
```

Comment: for `p1` in your CSS, do you mean `#p1` ? Also, do not nest `<p>` tag

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: @Paulie_D I thought the same thing.... but it's worth explaining to OP what their typographical error is, perhaps if there's a duplication.... (it's a simple error only because we *know*)

Comment: @Raptor it was a typo here. In the original css file, I wrote #p1 instead of p1 and that's why the second method works.

Comment: `<div id="p1"> paragraph1 </p> </div>` your syntax here is wrong. You should not be closing an unopened `<p>`, can you show us exactly what is on your HTML code, as you keep changing your code on the question it's akin to moving the goalposts for people to answer!

Answer (score 2):

In css `id` is define with `#` tag and class with `.` and `#` is missing in your css part

```
#p1{
   margin:0;
  }

#p2{
   margin:0;
  }
```

Comment: I was just about to comment the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

> **Please Note:** *This original answer was in reference to earlier versions of the Question, where the OP had made various syntax mistakes late corrected as typo's when writing the question out.*

To Summarise the excellent points raised in other posts and comments on this Q:

1) You are not addressing Id tags in your CSS. Please observe the different types of CSS referencing of elements, classes and ids on a page:

```
p1{
   /* This effects (ALL) elements on a page such as <p1></p1> */  
   margin:0;
  }
.p1{
   /* This effects classes only such as <p class='p1'></p> */
   margin:0;
  }
#p1{
   /* This effects id tagged elements such as <p id='p1'></p> */
   margin:0;
  }
```

2)

> ```
> <p id="p2">  <p> paragraph2 </p>
> ```

You are nesting/stacking your `<p>` elements. Stop it. Paragraph elements should not be nested. Close one before opening another. The correct structure is `<p>` inside `<div>`, the `id` tags can go anywhere on the page (but only appear *once*).

3)
 Solution to your original issue is to set the id in the `<p>` tag, *not* in the div container:

CSS:

```
#p1 {
    margin:0; 
}
```

HTML:

```
  <div> <p id="p1"> paragraph1 </p> </div>
```

> *Please note this is [not the only solution method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44304640/3536236).*

Comment: I encountered the issue after following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0afZj1G0BIE. In this youtube video, he included the ID's in the div containers. But you said the id should not be set in the div container. Then, isn't what he was doing the video wrong?

Comment: I don't see the code in your question at all on the youtube link you give. And while you can get a basic grounding of CSS in 12 minutes, you will get numerous issues such as your one because there's a lot more structure you need to learn. @KGalaxy

Answer (score 1):

If you want to format p tags use

```
p {
   margin:0;
}
```

Comment: this will effect *all* `<p>` tags

Comment: Therefore this is not a good answer, as OP only wants to effect specific elements